# Setting options of a select option from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I'm trying to read my options from an API so I made a Const InputResponse as follow:

```
const inputResponse = [
{
    key: 'news',
    value: "news",
    datagrid:{
        w:2,
        h:9,
        x:0,
        y:0,
        minW:2,
        minH:5
    }
},
{
    key: 'clock',
    value: "clock",
    datagrid:{
        w:2,
        h:5,
        x:5,
        y:0,
        minW:2,
        minH:5
    }
 }
]
```

but I have no clue how to effect my select option

```
 <Select defaultValue="" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={this.handleChange} >
                            <Option value="Clock" className="options">Clock</Option>
                            <Option value="News" className="options">News</Option>
                            <Option value="Yiminghe" className="options">yiminghe</Option>
                        </Select>
```

*the capital starting letters in jsx tags are for ant design*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate the array and just render it as is.
Like this:

```
 <Select style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  {
    this.inputResponse.map((item) => {
      return <Option value={item} key={item.key} className="options">{item.value}</Option>
    })
  }
 </Select>
```